# orm:schema-tool:create - Access denied

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am trying to add Doctrine to existing custom php application. The first issue that I've faced is the following:

when trying to run

```
$ php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

I get `Access denied`.

Here is the cli-config.php file that I am using:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$modelsPath = realpath(__DIR__.'/../model');
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array($modelsPath), true);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'database',
);

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet(EntityManager::create($conn, $config));
```

Where did I go wrong?

**UPDATE**

- php version is 5.4.6, OS
- Ubuntu 12.04,
- Doctrine Command Line
  Interface version 2.4.2
- vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine file is set as executable and own by the same user as the one trying to run it

**UPDATE**

As per this [discussion](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2486#comment-22763), I've been using a wrong driver. Corrections made - no effect.

Comment: Try with `chmod +x vendor/bin/doctrine`

Comment: Just did - no change :(

Comment: Operating system? Installation procedure followed so far?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, installed via composer

Comment: And also: is the PHP executable referenced at the beginning of `vendor/bin/doctrine` (or the referenced file) readable/executable for you?

Comment: I mean `/usr/bin/env php -r "echo 'hello world';"` - can you run that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49505/discussion-between-t1gor-and-ocramius)

Comment: Can you run `./vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine` manually?

Comment: Yes, I can: Doctrine Command Line Interface version 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar but server (also Ubuntu) was running on Vagrant. Executing PHP `vendor/bin/doctrine` `ORM:schema-tool:create` was giving:

```
1. Access denied (filesystem) or
2. Connection refused [MySQL] or
3. File not found [MySQL]
```

Solution was to ssh to vagrant machine and execute it from there.